# How to display an image in google search result

Tags: wordpress

How to display an Thumbnail image of my wordpress article in Google search result?Thanks in advance

Comment: I believe thats not possible. You can add an author badge or a kind oft rating in form of stars. Nothing more.

Comment: @morenulls, You can get thumbnails. Read my answer :)

Comment: @RishiDua, only for custom search, his question sounds like the normal Google search results.